# Is ESP32-based boards suitable for both Classic and BLE functionality?

Tags: esp32

I have an RPi4 which has an onboard BT/Wifi module produced by Cypress (Cypress CYW43455).

By using `BlueZ` on the RPi, I can run the following commands to use both Classic and BLE functionality:

```
l2ping MAC //this uses classic bluetooth
hcitool lescan //this uses BLE scan
gatttool //this uses BLE also
```

Now I don't know how `Cypress CYW43455` is interfaced with RPi4's CPU, but I want to reach the same functionality with using `ESP32` with RPi4 (probably via UART).

So my question is: (how) are ESP32-based boards capable of providing the same functionality  as the Cypress one?

I mean how:

- are they need to interface with RPi? (via UART? via USB? other?)
- is BlueZ working with ESP32 or other software is needed?

What I actually need is to

1. be able to "l2ping" a classic BT device
2. be able to read and write GATT data from/to a BLE device
3. be able to monitor BLE advertisement packages

Answer (score 1):

The Cypress chip is connected over UART to RPi. You can connect an ESP32 in the same way (using UART) and then use hciattach to attach it to the kernel.

Note that you need to flash the ESP32 with a firmware that connects hci to the uart port.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll need a few days to get this confirmed and I'll accept your great answer afterwards, as I might have additional details. Cheers

Comment: Can you point me any reference which shows this Cypress->UART->RPi connection? I believe Cypress also provides Wifi connection to RPi, and for this purpose UART might be slow. Or they are reaching 50-100Mbps over UART?

Comment: You can see in the CYW43455 datasheet how it talks to the host processor. Bluetooth uses UART and Wi-Fi uses a separate SDIO connection (which is faster than UART).